# O'Reilly book clarification on 2D linear system

Tags: opencv, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra, kalman-filter

The Oreilly book "Learning OpenCV" states at page 356 :

Quote

> Before we get totally lost, let’s consider a particular realistic situation of taking measurements
>   on a car driving in a parking lot. We might imagine that the state of the car could
>   be summarized by two position variables, x and y, and two velocities, vx and vy. These
>   four variables would be the elements of the state vector xk. Th is suggests that the correct form for F is:
>
> ```
> x = [ x; 
>       y;
>       vx;
>       vy; ]k
>
> F = [ 1, 0, dt, 0;  
>       0, 1, 0,  dt;
>       0, 0, 1,  0;
>       0, 0, 0,  1; ]
> ```

It seems natural to put 'dt' just there in the F matrix but I just don't get why. What if I have a n states system, how would I spray some "dt" in the F matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dt`s are coefficients of the velocities with the corresponding positions.  If you write your state update after time `dt` has elapsed:

```
x(t+dt) = x(t) + dt * vx(t)
y(t+dt) = y(t) + dt * vy(t)
vx(t+dt) = vx(t)
vy(t+dt) = vy(t)
```

You can read `F` off of these equations pretty easily.